# wxWidgets child sizer not expanding

Tags: wxwidgets, sizer

I've got a very frustrating sizer problem.

I have two `wxFlexGridSizer`s (and a few other things) inside a vertical `wxBoxSizer`, like so:

```
mMainSizer->Add(topsizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
mMainSizer->Add(1, lineheight);
mMainSizer->Add(mTypeLabel);
mMainSizer->Add(mTypeSizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
mMainSizer->Add(1, lineheight);
```

Each `wxFlexGridSizer` is filled using the same code:

```
sizer->Add(label, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
sizer->Add(fieldwidth, 1); // To separate label and data
sizer->Add(data, wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxRIGHT, rborder).Right());
```

But the `wxFlexGridSizer`s aren't being `Expand`ed to the same width, as I intend. The lower one, with smaller `label`s, is always narrower than the upper one, leaving the `data` fields misaligned between them. Since they were both added with the `Expand()` flag, the narrower one should expand to the same width as the wider one, right?

(I've even tried adding the `Right()` flag to the lower one too, when adding it to the `wxBoxSizer`, but it did nothing, which *really* confused me.)

Can anyone save my sanity by pointing out where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: As far as I can tell, this is a wxWidgets bug. The `Expand` flag should tell items in a vertical sizer to expand themselves to their maximum width. If I'm wrong, someone please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the bug was mine. I thought I'd given the `wxFlexGridSizer`s a growable column, with `wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol`, but that must have been in an earlier iteration of the code. Once I'd done that, they expanded just as I wanted them to.